# How to check if an array contains any item of another array

Tags: c#, arrays

Given 2 int arrays e.g, `foo` and `bar`, what's the most efficient way to check that the array bar contains at least one item that foo contains. should return true/false.

I'm suspecting nested `foreach` but just wondering if there's a nicer way?

Comment: Is this homework?  Are the arrays arbitrarily large, or smaller than, say, 100 elements?  Have you tried anything besides brute-force foreach?

Comment: no its not homework!... just figured there is probably a nice way of doing this.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
array1.Intersect(array2).Any()
```

Note: Using `Any()` assures that the intersection algorithm stops when the first equal object is found.

Comment: Using Any() assures that the intersection algorithm stops when the first equal object is found.

Comment: bear in mind that all of array1 is enumerated so you probably want the shorter array as array1 if possible

Comment: I never heard of the Intersect method so I had to look up what it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx It basically gives you a list of items that are found in both of the compared arrays. With the any operator you then know if array1 and array2 have any of the same strings in this case.

Answer (score 13):

C#3:

```
bool result = bar.Any(el => foo.Contains(el));
```

C#4 parallel execution:

```
bool result = bar.AsParallel().Any(el => foo.AsParallel().Contains(el));
```

Comment: In my case foo is substring of el. so, `bool result = bar.Any(el => foo.Contains(el));` will not give required result. Any suggestion how to implement this query?

Comment: In this case using `Any()` with `Contains()` is faster then other ways ;).

Answer (score 2):

Yes nested loops, although one is hidden:

```
bool AnyAny(int[] A, int[]B)
{
    foreach(int i in A)
       if (B.Any(b=> b == i))
           return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
var result = array1.Any(l2 => array2.Contains(l2)) == true ? "its there": "not there";
```

If you have class instead of built in datatypes like int etc, then need to override Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementation for your class.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct is optional depends of your first array (with or without unique value)...

```
String[] A = new String[] {"2","1","3","2"};
String[] B = new String[] {"1","2", "3", "3", "1", "1", "2"};
Console.WriteLine("A values: "+String.Join(", ",A));
Console.WriteLine("B values: "+String.Join(", ",B));
Console.WriteLine("Comparison A and B result: "+ A.Distinct().Intersect(B).SequenceEqual(A.Distinct()));
```

Answer (score -2):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)


    int[] arr1 = { 16, 48, 40, 32, 5, 7 };
    int[] arr2 = { 48, 32, 16, 40, 56, 72, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 5, 7, 6, 56 };
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.Length; j++)
        {

            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
            {
                k++;
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    if (arr1.Length == k)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(true);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine(false);
}
----
```

Comment: Posting code that seems to be very specialized for one case is not very helpful without further explanation.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score -3):

For one-shot random-array approach, your method seems to be the fastest. There are methods that would make it way more efficient if one or both matrices are sorted, their upper/lower bounds are known, or one of them changes way more rarely than the other one and you perform many checks. Thing is you can prepare various hashes, indices and hints that will optimize the search to nearly nothing, but the process of indexing alone will usually take more than a single search.

Comment: Good points, but it's not clear who you're talking to and it would have been helpful if you included some code directly related to OP q or a particular answer.

Comment: @G.Stoynev: I'm talking to the asker, which I believe what answers are supposed to be, and I doubt a nested 'foreach' comparison is complex enough to grant posting 'some code' - and unless OP qualifies the question with one of the 'special conditions' I'd mentioned there's no point guessing which would be applicable - for the general condition of single check on two arrays we know nothing about a nested foreach is the nicest solution.