# get collection with where clause as collection in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

Here is my service method:

```
 public List<RelatedInvoiceData> GetRelatedInvoices(InvoiceSearch invoiceSearchFilters)
 {
   List<InvoiceInfoView> invoices = _wiseStepDbContext.InvoiceInfoView.Where(i => i.RecruiterCompanyId == _securityManager.CurrentRecruiterCompanyId).ToList();

   List<RelatedInvoiceData> relatedInvoiceViewCollection = GetRelatedInvoiceCollection(invoices);

   if (invoiceSearchFilters.CustomerId > 0)
   {
        relatedInvoiceViewCollection = relatedInvoiceViewCollection.Where(i => i.CustomerId == invoiceSearchFilters.CustomerId).ToList();
   }

   if (invoiceSearchFilters.VendorId > 0)
   {
        relatedInvoiceViewCollection = relatedInvoiceViewCollection.Where(i => i.VendorId == invoiceSearchFilters.VendorId).ToList();
   }

   return relatedInvoiceViewCollection;
}
```

here is my filterObject :

```
public class InvoiceSearch
    {
        public int[] CustomerId { get; set; }

        public int[] VendorId { get; set; }
    }
```

Previously I used where in linq for single customer Id now i want filter with multiple customerIds and multiple VendorIds.

Now I want to go with array of CustomerIds. How to write LINQ for Array in Where clause. Thanks for any help

Comment: Sort of depends on what variation of LINQ you're using (e.g. LINQ to Objects, LINQ to Entities, etc.).  Different variations support a different subset of operators and operations.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you mean that `i.CustomerId` is now an array or `List<>`.  If that's the case, then you can use  the`.Contains()` method.  Something like this should do what you want: `relatedInvoiceViewCollection = relatedInvoiceViewCollection.Where(i => i.CustomerId.Contains(invoiceSearchFilters.CustomerId)).ToList();`

**Edit:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2266012/3504957) may be helpful if you want to check for [intersections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) in two arrays, which you can do in your case like this:`relatedInvoiceViewCollection = relatedInvoiceViewCollection.Where(i => i.CustomerId.Intersect(invoiceSearchFilters.CustomerId).Any()).ToList();`

Comment: I may be wrong in giving the questions, I have updated the question with clear requirement. check with the question update the Ans

Answer (score 0):

```
relatedInvoiceViewCollection.Where(x => relatedInvoiceViewCollection.Contains(invoiceSearchFilters.CustomerId)).ToList();
```

or

```
relatedInvoiceViewCollection.Where(x => x.Contains(invoiceSearchFilters.CustomerId)).ToList();
```

Comment: my mistake in asking the right question. Updated the question please check with the requirement and update the ans.